# How to define array of string of ArrayList of String

Tags: java, hibernate

```
private List<String> getReportedData(List<TSAMMGFSScfInvoiceCreditData> extractedData,
        List<TSAMMGFSScfHolidayData> extractedHolidayData) {
    int invoiceCount = 0;
    int creditMemoCount = 0;
    BigDecimal totalAmount_INV = new BigDecimal(0);
    BigDecimal totalAmount_CM = new BigDecimal(0);
    List<String> mgfData = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuffer reportData = new StringBuffer();

    Date currentDate = new Date();
    String presentDate = DateUtil.formatDate(currentDate);
    reportData.append(getheader());

    List<String> mgfHolidayData = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < extractedHolidayData.size(); i++) {

        TSAMMGFSScfHolidayData holidayData = extractedHolidayData.get(i);
        mgfHolidayData.add(DateUtil.formatDate(holidayData.getHOLIDAYDATE()).toString());
    }
```

Instead of using `extractedHolidayData.get(i)` how can I use just array of String so that I don't have to create data object `TSAMMGFSScfHolidayData` and `hbm.xml`

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking. We have no idea what a `TSAMMGFSScfHolidayData` object contains, nor how a String could possibly be used in its place.

Comment: @rmlan TSAMMGFSScfHolidayData  simple pojo class(hibernate configuration). Let me ask you this...how would I get the all the getHOLIDAYDATE at once instead of looping it one by one?

Comment: It would appear as though you are transforming a value from the object, so I don't really see a way that you could "get it all at once" and still achieve what you appear to be attempting to achieve. What is your concern? Performance?

Comment: Are you asking how would you convert an ArrayList of string to string array ?

Comment: @rmlan Yes performance. I have these two data objects TSAMMGFSScfInvoiceCreditData and TSAMMGFSScfHolidayData which have different query getting me some values. I being told to

Comment: There is no need of holiday data object (TSAMMGFSScfHolidayData and hbm.xml), requires config changes.

It has just two columns (holiday key and date), holiday key which is just sequence number and really not needed. You can use just array of String instead.

Comment: instead of  extractedHolidayData.get(i).............you can define array of string of ArrayList of String and do the same
ArrayList<String> extractedHolidayData
and do the same

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Does it making any sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is :

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select t.listOfwhatYouNeed from TSAMMGFSScfHolidayData t");
List<Object[]> yourStringObjects= (List<Object[]>)q.list();
```

After that you can cast those objects to String.

That is the simplest solution I can think of but not the best thing to do. Hibernate is an ORM tool and it's best practices should be followed.